# Did the Nazis kill Jews with gas chambers?

Tags: history, world-war-ii, germany, holocaust

I just heard Holocaust denier and former academic, [Robert Faurisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Faurisson), explaining a few things about gas chambers.

What he claims :

- The dilapidated chambers, thought to be gas chambers in the Nazi death camps are not secure enough to send Zyklon B in them. In the US jails, when a guy is sentenced to death,  it's a very hard job for safety reasons. The wooden doors of the gas chamber can't contain gas, the glass windows in those chamber are not secure enough to avoid prisoners breaking them, etc.
- There are no pictures of those gas mass-killing chambers. There are no plans of them. All we have are reconstructions based of the descriptions of very few prisoners.
- There is insufficient evidence that they were used as gas chambers.

Is this a view supported by evidence?

(source *warning this is in french* : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9_6rE8VoPo)

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22491/did-nazis-use-alternatives-to-zyklon-b

Comment: Related question has a different answer, because as a base of discussion it defined as acquired the fact that there was gas chambers

Comment: I agree, that's why it's only *related* and not a *duplicate*. If two questions are the same answer, one will be closed as duplicate of the other. The "related" comment is only to guide visitors to an extra question if they like yours.

Comment: "Jews" might be irrelevant here as they also killed many non-jews in their concentration camps.

Comment: Regarding point 1, in his analogy does Mr Faurisson attempt to address the difference that malnourished, starving concentration camp victims bundled into what they are told is a "shower building" have a much lower level of physical strength and prior knowledge of their predicament than well-fed, well-exercised, well-informed American death row inmates?

Comment: "In the US jails, when a guy is sentenced to death, it's a very hard job for safety reasons." - Somehow I doubt the Nazis showed a modern level of concern for general safety best-practices.

Comment: The peace time safety standards are normally much higher than the war time safety standards. If a few  less careful executors got poisoned with they victims (maybe not completely to death) probably nobody cared.

Comment: Please take care of your wording. Faurisson is not *explaining a few things about gas chambers* in the texts you quote. He is putting forth arguments for his theories. Arguing is not explaining.

Comment: I would like to comment that I find questions like these, accompanied by proper answers, to be decisively invaluable. Reason? The Holocaust may not be nailed down in every detail, but it is as historically documented, and researchable, as pretty much anything else historical. Consequently, sophistry attempting to dismiss obvious conclusions represent a live capture of spin doctoring at its most significant. If you care about sophistry and spin doctoring obscuring the truth, these kinds of questions, not only *answered* but **analyzed**, provide a goldmine for glimpsing how deception works.

Comment: Zyklon B was originally sold as a pesticide. They used to fumigate ships, trains, factories, hospitals, and people's homes with it. They even used to fumigate orchards with it. The Germans invented jet powered planes, liquid fueled self-guided ICBMs, freeways, and were the first nation in space. It didn't take a lot of engineering resources to figure out how to lock a bunch of people in a small room and fill it with an agricultural pesticide with only the occasional mishap. And as they used other prisoners to perform this task I'd guess that they had few concerns about occupational safety.

Comment: What do people GET out of this denial anyway? What is the point?

Comment: @nocomprende, people like "being in the know".  They want to be special, and what could make you more special than knowing that millions of other people are _wrong_.

Comment: @Spoutnik16 it would be good if you sourced each of the claims to specific documents by Faurisson

Comment: all those claims come from a 2h talk in french :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9_6rE8VoPo

Comment: Keep in mind that prisoners were told to go take a shower to avoid suspicion, when enough of them were gathered in such a chamber a canister of gas was dropped through a hatch-like opening in the ceiling. The door was locked already and any prisoners trying to escape through the windows (I don't think these chambers had windows though) were probably shot anyway.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but in a hollywood movie depicted the spread of strong stench in and around the camps. I thought that the chambers were used to burn the inmates, but I now realize they were gassed. Could the stench be due to the rotting bodies then?

Comment: The Zyklon B that was used was in a gaseous state.  Gas rises so It could conceivably float away on the outside of the death chambers with affecting the guards if they are not close enough.  The poison is inhaled to cause the effects. a mask would help to prevent the effects.  Part of the problems in America is that the chamber is in a building with a viewing room which is also filled with people.  no where for the gas to go.

Comment: Fun fact, this is illegal in some (mostly European) countries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_against_Holocaust_denial

Comment: @h22, peace time safety standards are actually *much* lower than wartime ones. For the simple reason that if something goes wrong in peace time, there is damage/loss and repair. In wartime if there is damage/loss your enemy takes advantage of it and there might not be a country of yours to repair the damage later. Sorry, but obviously you have never been in the military or you'd know they have THE highest safety standards that are enforced 24/7 being lax in safety in military temrs is being perfectly spotless in civilian terms.

Comment: @JohnSwaringen gases that are denser than air sink rather than rising, which is how poison gas in WWI was effective against soldiers in the trenches.

Comment: I think what's being missed in the discussion of not following some kind of safety standard is that the US, even with executions, has a prohibition on *cruel and unusual* punishments, which would probably create a much greater procedural difference vs the level of occupational safety standards.  If the killing process took much longer because of a cheaper less rigorous process, and the people suffered gruesomely for a long period of time before dying, that's probably not an impediment for a genocidal extermination campaign.

Comment: The delousing gas chambers need ~16000ppm for ~72 hrs vs 300ppm for 15 min for humans (https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/holocaust-denial-and-the-big-lie). Thus the higher concentration of residues in said chambers. Indeed, vacuum incapacitates humans in seconds but not flies (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4h-AS729JM).

Answer (score 266, accepted):

The statements of Robert Faurisson **plainly contradict and ignore a vast body of primary sources and academic research on the topic**. Some of the documents that address the use of gas chambers by the Nazi regime during WWII include the following:

- Writing for the *[Journal of Holocaust and Genocide Studies](http://hgs.oxfordjournals.org/content/16/2/189.full.pdf+html)* historian Michael Thad Allen (Georgia Institute of Technology) summarizes available research and cites original documents from German and East European archives documenting technical details of gas chambers used at Birkenau and Auschwitz. Contrary to the claims, these include blueprints, purchasing orders, and official German communications (which were carried out openly). The author concluded to say:

  > The precedents were Zyklon‐B chambers for delousing clothing, a
  >   technology widely known throughout a network of specialized firms. Far
  >   from pursuing the halting and somewhat inconscient development of gas
  >   chambers in Birkenau heretofore presented in the historical
  >   literature, the SS first took an interest in Zyklon‐B chambers in the
  >   summer of 1941, and by early October the Central Building Directorate
  >   of Auschwitz intentionally and systematically had adapted such
  >   equipment to the gassing of human beings.<sup>1</sup>

  [image: Crematoria & Gas Chamber Plans]

  <sub>**Illustration**: "An examination of [...] the forced air ventilation system reveals that the ZBL-Auschwitz Planned Morgue 1 of Crematoria II [pictured] as a gigantic Zyclon-B extermination facility."<sup>1</sup></sub>
- The evidence for gas chambers was tested in court on numerous occasions. For an archive of court-tested evidence see *[Law Reports of Trials of War Criminals](http://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/law-reports-trials-war-criminals.html)* in 15 volumes, published for the United Nations War Crimes Commission by His Majesty's Stationary Office and hosted at the US Library of Congress. Volume I, page 93 contains documents related to the "Zyklon B Case: Trial of Bruno Tesch and Two Others" **charged with and found guilty** of "Complicity in the murder of interned allied civilians by means of poison gas."<sup>2</sup>

  In the case (V. X, page 24) against I.G. Farben the German chemical industry conglomerate, Karl Krauch, Walter Duerrfeld, Otto Ambros, Heinrich Buetefisch, and Fritz ter Meer were **accused and found guilty** of supplying large quantities of Zyklon-B that was "used in the mass extermination of inmates of concentration camps, including Auschwitz."<sup>7</sup>
- During war crime trials held in the years of 1947-1949 multiple witnesses, on separate occasions, appearing before a variety of legal bodies, in independent jurisdictions, have testified to witnessing the use of gas chambers for mass extermination of prisoners. These include sworn testimony by survivors Annie Jonnas, Abraham Glinowieski, Lidia Sunschein, Helen Klein, Gertrude Diament, and Dr. Bendel among many others.<sup>3,8</sup>
- Multiple German Nazi officials, on separate occasions, appearing before a variety of legal bodies, in independent jurisdictions, have freely admitted to carrying out the various aspects of using gas chambers for the mass extermination of prisoners. These include, among many others, Josef Kramer, Commandant of the Bergen-Belsen concentration camp, who spoke at length in front of a British court about the gassing program at Bergen-Belsen and at Natzweiller;<sup>3</sup> Franz Hofmann,  Schutzhaftlagerführer in Auschwitz, who testified in the Frankfurt trials before a German court in 1963-1965;<sup>9</sup> and Oskar Gröning, SS-Unterscharführer at Auschwitz, who testified before a court in Lower Saxony (Germany) in 2015.<sup>10</sup>
- The proceedings of the trial against Rudolf Franz Ferdinand Hoess, Commandant of the Auschwitz Camp concluded:

  > Over four million people from all countries occupied by Germany met with with death in the gas-chambers and crematoria installed in the camp.<sup>5</sup>

  The prosecution in the case of Josef Kramer, Commandant of the Bergen-Belsen concentration camp, concluded:

  > Could the court have the slightest doubt about the gas chamber or the selections that were made for the gas chamber? It was freely admitted that there were in camp Birkenau five gas chambers attached to the crematoria [...] There was no doubt whatsoever [...] in Auschwitz alone literally millions of people were gassed for no other reason that they were Jews.<sup>3</sup>

  In the case of the Josef Altstotter, Reichministerialdirektor, before the United States Military Tribunal in Nuremberg in 1947 the Tribunal concluded that:

  > A certain number of the concentration camps were equipped with with gas chambers for the wholesale destruction of the inmates, and with furnaces for the burning of the bodies.<sup>4</sup>

  In a war crimes case against Gauleiter Greiser, SS-Obergruppenführer and Reichsstatthalter of Wartheland (Poland), the Supreme National Tribunal of Poland found the defendant guilty of

  > wholesale extermination of Polish citizens of Jewish race [who were] concentrated in a small number of ghettos, deported, [and finally] murdered, mainly in the gas-chambers of the extermination camp at Chelmno.<sup>8</sup>

The documents I cite above embody a small fraction of the available factual record on the matter. They represent the testimony of hundreds, the research and verification effort of thousands, and the experience of millions.

While it is possible to contest some of the technical details in any one given document (the historical record is never perfect), the sheer number and variety of sources, their legitimacy in the eyes of the law, and their acceptance by the peer-reviewed academic community builds an **overwhelming case for the Nazi regime's use of gas chambers in the mass extermination of Jews and other prisoner populations.** Did the Holocaust really happen? Yes. The wholesale dismissal of established (if not always precise) historical facts in favor of speculation and innuendo is in effect a sign of conspiratorial thinking in general and Holocaust denial in particular.

1. Allen, Michael Thad. “The Devil in the Details: The Gas Chambers of Birkenau, October 1941.” *[Holocaust and Genocide Studies](http://hgs.oxfordjournals.org/content/16/2/189.short)* 16, no. 2 (January 1, 2002): 189–216.
2. United Nations War Crimes Commission. *[Law Reports of Trials of War Criminals](http://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/law-reports-trials-war-criminals.html)*. Vol I. London: His Majesty’s Stationary Office, 1947.
3. United Nations War Crimes Commission. *[Law Reports of Trials of War Criminals](http://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/law-reports-trials-war-criminals.html)*. Vol II. London: His Majesty’s Stationary Office, 1947.
4. United Nations War Crimes Commission. *[Law Reports of Trials of War Criminals](http://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/law-reports-trials-war-criminals.html)*. Vol VI. London: His Majesty’s Stationary Office, 1948.
5. United Nations War Crimes Commission. *[Law Reports of Trials of War Criminals](http://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/law-reports-trials-war-criminals.html)*. Vol VII. London: His Majesty’s Stationary Office, 1948.
6. The French historian Georges Didi-Huberman takes up the subject of photographic evidence in his book-length monograph *Images in Spite of All*, published by the University of Chicago Press in 2008.
   Didi-Huberman, Georges. *[Images in spite of all: four photographs from Auschwitz](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/I/bo5907594.html)*. Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2008.
7. United Nations War Crimes Commission. *[Law Reports of Trials of War Criminals](http://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/law-reports-trials-war-criminals.html)*. Vol X. London: His Majesty’s Stationary Office, 1949.
8. United Nations War Crimes Commission. *[Law Reports of Trials of War Criminals](http://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/law-reports-trials-war-criminals.html)*. Vol XIII. London: His Majesty’s Stationary Office, 1949.
9. Wittmann, Rebecca. *[Beyond Justice the Auschwitz Trial](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674063877)*. Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press, 2005.
10. "[Beihilfe zum Mord durch eine Tätigkeit im Konzentrationslager Auschwitz](http://www.rechtsprechung.niedersachsen.de/jportal/portal/page/bsndprod.psml?doc.id=KORE221452015&st=null&showdoccase=1)." Rechtsprechung der niedersächsischen Justiz. 15.07.2015.

Comment: You might also consider the more recent statements of Oskar Gröning, The Wikipedia article cites a variety of reasonably reputable news sources, here is the sentencing: http://www.rechtsprechung.niedersachsen.de/jportal/portal/page/bsndprod.psml?doc.id=KORE221452015&st=null&showdoccase=1

Comment: Clarifying the blueprint image's content: The German labels of [the blueprint shown](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OzyTD.png) (from source 1; M. T. Allen) describe a *generic delousing chamber*, which could also have been used to delouse clothing—nothing about the design or labels suggests this particular design was intended for murder. However, the [diagrams of *crematoria with attached gas chambers*](http://www.ihr.org/jhr/v10/v10p461_Mattogno.html) are much more damning, as such facilities are not otherwise explainable.

Comment: @o.m. added a reference in the testimony of nazi officials section

Comment: While the question is mostly about Zyklon-B, it is surely worth noting that a large number of holocaust victims was actually gased with motor exhaust fumes. For example, in the three camps which were created solely for extermination (Treblinka, Belzec, and Sobibor) more than 1.5m Jews were killed by exhaust fumes. The method was first widely used in the Nazi euthanasia program *Aktion T4* with ca. 70000 victims.

Comment: You need to be careful with the quote about Josef Kramer to avoid confusion: it was about gas chambers at Birkenau (Auschwitz No. 2) and there was no suggestion at his trial of gas chambers at Bergen-Belsen. Kramer had been Kommandant at Birkenau and than later at Bergen-Belsen.

Comment: On the other hand, Kramer claiming "Selections for the gas chambers or working-camps were carried out only by doctors, and Auschwitz No.1 was responsible for keeping order on these occasions" is an admission of the existence and use of the gas chambers at Birkenau.  Kramer was hanged as a result of the trial

Comment: @Henry, yes great point. I mean only to mention that he freely admitted to the existence of the gassing program.

Comment: @Anko Thank you for the comment. I uploaded a better diagram and changed the caption to make it more clear. The cited article gives the appropriate technical context (which is too long to fit here).

Comment: @FelixDombek fair point. We can only tell a part of the story here.

Comment: There was a "mountain of evidence" that Iraq had WMDs. Quantity does not imply quality.

Comment: @KeithMcClary I disagree strongly. The evidence for WMDs in Iraq was classified and not subject to independent scholarly verification. The evidence for gas chambers has withstood the test of time, verified in multiple courts, in multiple independent jurisdictions, and subject to careful academic study, peer review, and publication. You are offering a false equivalence. Diversity of verification methods does imply quality.

Comment: @KeithMcClary and that evidence was verified and found in large part correct after the 2003 invasion. It was just that incorrect conclusions were drawn from it, in that there were no large quantities of WNDs found despite there being a large number of storage and manufacturing facilities as well as partial products like bomb casings for poison gas. The weapons themselves were not detected prior to 2003, quite different from gas chambers and their operations detected at the liberation of the extermination camps in Germany at the end of WW2

Answer (score 109):

Regarding the claims of Robert Faurisson,

1. **Gas chambers:** [Rudolf Höß, the Auschwitz Kommandant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_H%C3%B6ss) swore in an affidavit that Zyklon-B was dropped into the death chamber through a small opening.

   Referring to Pery Broad's testimony,

   > He described how the area surrounding the crematorium was kept closed. The Jews arrived in columns. They were told they were going to be disinfected. After they entered the chamber, the door was bolted. The contents of tins of Zyklon-B were thrown into the chamber through six holes in the roof.

   Referring to Kula's testimony,

   > Kula testified that four wire mesh columns were made for the gas chambers in crematoria 2 and 3: these columns were described by Kula as "structures of ever finer mesh", which contained a removable can within the innermost column which was used to extract, after the gassing, the Zyklon "crystals" or pellets that had absorbed the hydrocyanide.

   Also documents from February 1943 referred to the provision of gastight doors and windows.

   > In a letter dated 31 March 1943 Bischoff presses for the delivery of a gastight door with a spyhole of 8mm glass, with a rubber seal and metal fitting. There is a timesheet of a construction worker which makes reference to fitting gastight windows to crematorium.
2. **Pictures or plans of gas mass-killing chambers:** After the revelations in the Allied media concerning the gas chambers at the camp at Majdanek in late 1944, Himmler had ordered the dismantling of the extermination installations in the crematoria at Auschwitz. In late 1944 the Nazis duly dynamited the crematoria and destroyed the camp archives. Only the documents from the Central Construction Office archives accidentally survived.

Nazis used [gas](http://www.holocaustresearchproject.org/othercamps/auschwitzgaschambers.html) chambers to kill both Jews and non-Jews by the historic and forensic evidence listed below.

1. **Speeches by Nazi officials:**  Speeches by Heinrich Luitpold Himmler and Paul Joseph Goebbels confirm the plans of extermination for Jews.

   Himmler's speech at Posen on October 4, 1943 was captured on audiotape (Trial of the Major War Criminals, 1948, Vol. XXIX, p. 145):

   > I refer now to the evacuation of the Jews, the extermination of the Jewish people. This is one of those things that is easily said: "the Jewish people are being exterminated," says every Party member, "quite true, it's part of our plans, the elimination of the Jews, extermination, we're doing it."

   Goebbels (as translated in Lochner, The Goebbels Diaries, 1948, pp. 86, 147-148):

   > February 14, 1942: The Führer once again expressed his determination to clean up the Jews in Europe pitilessly. There must be no squeamish sentimentalism about it. The Jews have deserved the catastrophe that has now overtaken them. Their destruction will go hand in hand with the destruction of our enemies. We must hasten this process with cold ruthlessness.
   >
   > March 27, 1942: The procedure is a pretty barbaric one and not to be described here more definitely. Not much will remain of the Jews. On the whole it can be said that about 60 per cent of them will have to be liquidated whereas only 40 per cent can be used for forced labor.

   Six extermination camps were established between 1941 and 1943. The extermination camps can be divided into two groups: the “pure” extermination camps and the combined extermination/concentration camps.

   **“Pure" extermination camps (Chelmno and the Operation Reinhard camps):**
   Four camps, Belzec, Sobibor, Treblinka (the Operation Reinhard camps) and Chelmno were all “pure” extermination facilities.

   > In 1942, systematic mass killing in stationary gas chambers (with carbon monoxide gas generated by diesel engines) began at Belzec, Sobibor, and Treblinka, all in Poland. As victims were "unloaded" from cattle cars, they were told that they had to be disinfected in "showers." The Nazi and Ukrainian guards sometimes shouted at and beat the victims, who were ordered to enter the "showers" with raised arms to allow as many people as possible to fit into the gas chambers. The tighter the gas chambers were packed, the faster the victims suffocated.

   **Combined extermination/concentration camps (Auschwitz-Birkenau and Majdanek):** Both of these camps were originally concentration camps. In time, however, they were included in the organised mass murder, following the construction of gas chambers.

   > The Nazis constantly searched for more efficient means of extermination. At the Auschwitz camp in Poland, they conducted experiments with Zyklon B (previously used for fumigation) by gassing some 600 Soviet prisoners of war and 250 ill prisoners in September 1941. Zyklon B pellets, converted to lethal gas when exposed to air. They proved the quickest gassing method and were chosen as the means of mass murder at Auschwitz.
2. **Written documents:** Orders for Zyklon-B [gas](http://www.nizkor.org/faqs/auschwitz/auschwitz-faq-06.html), [blueprints](http://www.ihr.org/jhr/v10/v10p461_Mattogno.html) and orders for building materials for the crematoria, etc.

   **Orders for Zyklon-B**- In a letter requesting for a truck to bring Zyklon-B to Auschwitz, the term "resettlement of Jews" is used as a camouflage term to refer to extermination.  Another document asks for "material for special treatment" which is another term used to refer to extermination which is present [here](http://www.nizkor.org/ftp.cgi/people/l/leuchter.fred/leuchter.faq2).

   > The first and most significant body of such evidence is the blue print material, which consists of a series of architectural drawings which depict the adaptation of crematoria 2 and 3 and the construction of crematoria 4 and 5. None of these drawings refers overtly to any part of the buildings being designed or intended to serve as gas chambers whether for fumigation or extermination purposes. In particular the drawings for Leichenkeller (morgue) 1 in crematorium 2 make no provision for ducts or chimneys by means of which Zyklon-B pellets might be inserted through the roof.
3. **Eyewitness testimony from camp officials, employees and prisoners:** Sonderkommando [diaries](http://www.brandeis.edu/tauber/publications/roskies/suchoff_lr.pdf), [SS](http://www.unwcc.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Groening-UNWCC-documents.pdf) officer Oskar Gröning, confessions of guards such as SS-Unterscharfuehrer Pery [Broad](http://holocaustcontroversies.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-reliable-and-authentic-is-broad.html) and commandants such as SS- Obersturmbannfuehrer Rudolf [Hoess](http://law2.umkc.edu/faculty/projects/ftrials/nuremberg/hoesstest.html) and SS-Hauptsturmfuhrer (Captain) Hans [Aumeier](http://www.holocaustresearchproject.org/othercamps/chainofcommand.html) who admitted that gas chambers had been in operation in Auschwitz and that on many occasions they had been used for killing Jews.

   > The principal of these Rudolf Hoss, the Auschwitz Kommandant, was captured by the British on 11th March 1946. In the course of his interrogation at Nuremberg Hoss produced a detailed list of the numbers of people transported to Auschwitz from various countries in Europe. The list totalled well over one million. When asked how so large a number could be accommodated at the camp, given that Hoss had said that there were facilities for only 130,000 at the camp, Hoss answered that most of those transported to the camp were taken there to be exterminated.
   >
   > Hoss later swore an affidavit in which he admitted that he had overseen the extermination, by gassing and burning, of at least two and a half million people. He stated that Zyklon-B was dropped into the death chamber through a small opening. It took from 3 to 15 minutes to kill those in the chamber. After half an hour the bodies were removed. Sonderkommandos or Special commandos removed their rings and extracted the gold from their teeth. Hoss described the process by which those to be gassed were selected. He stated that attempts were made to deceive the victims that they were going to be deloused. He said that the gas chambers were capable of accommodating 2,000 people at one time. Dr Gustav Gilbert, the Nuremberg prison psychologist, recorded in his diary an account of a conversation with Hoss in which he confirmed that two and a half million people had been exterminated under his direction.
4. **Photographs:** Photos taken of the burning of bodies that were smuggled out of [Auschwitz](https://d3gxp3iknbs7bs.cloudfront.net/attachments/600aa73def7bcb987eb13bf67a9186f1c9af4c39.pdf) and of the [women](http://bassin-lemans-72.ac-nantes.fr/site_hist_geo/partenariats/JPBNY2007/jpbnang/mandelbaum.htm) on the way to gas chambers.
5. **The Auschwitz Protocols:** Rudolph Vrba and Alfred Wetzler were Slovak Jewish prisoners who escaped from Auschwitz in April 1944. They prepared a comprehensive [report](http://www.holocaustresearchproject.org/othercamps/auschproto.html) on what was happening at Auschwitz, and sent it to the West. The information about Auschwitz included relatively accurate drawings of its main camps and the extermination facilities.
6. **Nazi officer evidence for destruction of records:** Nazi officers such Rudolf Hoss and Adolf Eichmann have confirmed to have received [orders](http://hdot.org/en/learning/myth-fact/hitlerorder.html) to destroy all records related to the extermination.

   > Rudolf Höss, the Commandant of Auschwitz, wrote after the war that Adolf Eichmann, the bureaucrat in charge of organizing the deportations of Jews to the death camps, was "the only SS officer who was allowed to keep records concerning these liquidation operations, according to the orders of the Reichsführer-SS [Himmler]. All other units which took part in any way had to destroy all records immediately."
   >
   > Adolf Eichmann, in his memoirs, which were taped by a reporter named Willem Sassen and then turned into a book, Ich: Adolf Eichmann, published in 1980, said: "Around the end of 1941 or the beginning of 1942 Heydrich, the Chef of the SIPO [Security Police] and SD [Security Service], told me in conversation that the Führer had ordered the physical destruction of the Jewish opponent."
7. **Camp remains:** The Auschwitz camp complex was located near the small Polish town of Oswiecim, about thirty-two miles southwest of Cracow.
   Auschwitz consisted of several camps. Auschwitz I (Auschwitz-Zasole (The "Stammlager" - Original Camp, Headquarters for the entire complex) served mainly as a concentration camp, Auschwitz II (Auschwitz-Birkenau) or Birkenau, primarily as a killing facility, and Auschwitz III (Auschwitz-Buna) or Monowitz, a forced labor camp. Forced labor was used throughout the Auschwitz system and several smaller forced labor camps served as satellites of Auschwitz.

   Birkenau became the largest killing facility in the German Reich. Its four crematoria could gas and incinerate thousands of people each day. Forensic examination conducted showed demonstration of the homicidal use of both the gas chambers and the crematoria for the purpose of exterminating large numbers of [prisoners](http://www.phdn.org/negation/pressac-leuchter.html) per Pressac.

   Research in [1990](http://www.nizkor.org/ftp.cgi/orgs/polish/institute-for-forensic-research/post-leuchter.report) by  Jan Markiewicz et.al. showed that Cyanide residue was found in high concentrations in the delousing chambers, and lower concentrations in the homicidal gas chambers which is consistent with the amounts required to kill lice and humans.

   > The present study shows that in spite of the passage  of a considerable period of time (over 45 years) in the walls  of the  facilities  which  once were in contact  with  hydrogen cyanide  the vestigial amounts of the combinations of this constituent  of Zyklon B have been preserved. This  is  also true of the ruins of the former gas chambers. The  cyanide compounds  occur in the building materials only locally,  in the  places  where the conditions arose for their  formation and persistence for such a long time.
8. **Polish Central Commission for Investigation of German [Crimes](http://www.hdot.org/en/trial/judgement/07-8.html):**

   > In 1945 the forensic laboratory in Cracow carried out an analysis of, firstly, zinc covers removed from the alleged gas chambers at Birkenau and, secondly, 25.5kg of human hair recovered from the camp. Both were found to contain traces of cyanide.
9. **Olere drawings:** David Olere was a painter who was deported to Auschwitz in March 1943. He worked in the Sonderkommando living in the attic of Crematorium 3 and observed the building and related activity. He has also produced over fifty sketches in 1945-46.

   > Olere's sketches are corroborated by plans that the Russians found in the Central Construction Office, save that Olere depicts vertical wire mesh columns in the gas chamber which are not to be found in the original architectural plans for the site. Olere's arrangement has the mesh columns attached to the west side of the first and fifth structural columns and on the east side of the third and seventh structural columns in the gas chamber.
10. **Numbers evidence:** Research on documentation provided the numbers of prisoners shipped to the various camps, the numbers that were transferred, and the number liberated. The difference between the latter with the former two figures gives an approximation of the numbers who died or were killed per The Destruction of the European Jews by Hilberg, [1961](http://www.history.ac.uk/reviews/review/394).

    Construction of the gas chambers and the method of killing is researched extensively by a former Holocaust denier Jean-Claude Pressac in [1989](http://www.holocaust-history.org/auschwitz/pressac/technique-and-operation/pressac0011.shtml) and further denials by  an American execution technician Fred A. Leuchter  are analyzed in a [document](http://www.nizkor.org/ftp.cgi/people/l/leuchter.fred/leuchter.faq2) called 'The Leuchter Report: A Layman's Guide'.
11. **Judgement Statement of the Judge Thomas T. Johnson regarding gassing of Jews:** Referring to a case between Mel Mermelstein, an Auschwitz survivor and an organization called IHR in [1981](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Holocaust/denial1.html), no "credible evidence" was produced for disproving the existence of gas chambers for the purpose of killing human beings at or in Auschwitz.

    > The Honorable Thomas T. Johnson, on October 9, 1981, took judicial notice as follows:
    >
    > Under Evidence Code Section 452(h), this court does take judicial notice of the fact that Jews were gassed to death at the Auschwitz Concentration Camp in Poland during the summer of 1944 ... It just simply is a fact that falls within the definition of Evidence Code Section 452(h). It is not reasonably subject to dispute. And it is capable of immediate and accurate determination by resort to sources of reasonably indisputable accuracy. It is simply a fact.
12. **Judgement Statement of the Judge Hon. Mr. Justice Gray about existence of gas chambers at Auschwitz**: In [2000](http://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/QB/2000/115.html#7), in a case between David John Cadwell Irving and Penguin Books Limited

    > Having considered the various arguments advanced by Irving to assail the effect of the convergent evidence relied on by the Defendants, it is my conclusion that no objective, fair-minded historian would have serious cause to doubt that there were gas chambers at Auschwitz and that they were operated on a substantial scale to kill hundreds of thousands of Jews.
13. **Evidence of underground gas chamber roofs**: The underground room, called Leichenkeller 1 on the German blueprints, was in fact a homicidal poison gas chamber, used to kill many thousands of Jews during the latter years of World War II per Peter [Myers](http://mailstar.net/holocaust-debate20.html).

    > We are left with one other form of evidence: archaeological. This evidence shows that there are three locations on the roof which fit the evidence of the eyewitnesses regarding the presence of roof holes. But based upon the collapse of the 20 year old Revisionist assertion that there "are no holes in the roof of Krema 2's gas chamber", we would be willing to place a large bet that one is there too.
14. **Calculation of the quantity of Zyklon-B required for fumigation:** The amount of Zyklon-B delivered to Auschwitz vastly exceeded the quantity delivered to other camps when calculated by Professor Robert Jan van Pelt, Professor of Architecture in the School of Architecture, University of Waterloo in Canada who is an acknowledged authority on Auschwitz. Total Zyklon B Ordered for Auschwitz camps in 1943 was 12,000 kg which was an increase of 60% (160% of 7500) when compared to total Zyklon B of 7500 kg ordered for Auschwitz camps in 1942.

    > He made a detailed calculation, based on delivery documents and on stated assumptions about the frequency of fumigations, that of the total amount of Zyklon-B delivered to [Auschwitz](http://www.ihr.org/jhr/v04/v04p261_Lindsey.html) in 1943 (12,000 kilos) not more than 9,000 kilos would have been required for fumigation. That would leave unaccounted for 3,000 kilos, which van Pelt contended would have been more than enough to kill the 250,000 Jews estimated to have been gassed to death that year.

According to figures provided by the Auschwitz-Birkenau State Museum, the overall number of victims of Auschwitz in the years 1940-1945 is estimated at between 1,100,000 and 1,500,000 people. The majority of them, and above all the mass transports of Jews who arrived beginning in 1942, died in the gas chambers.

> Jews were not the only victims of this Nazi German killing machine - historians estimate that among the people sent to Auschwitz there were at least 1,100,000 Jews from all the countries of occupied Europe, over 140,000 Poles (mostly political prisoners), approximately 20,000 Gypsies from several European countries, over 10,000 Soviet prisoners of war, and over 10,000 prisoners of other nationalities.
>
> Between 750,000 and 950,000 Jews were killed by gas at Treblinka; 550,000 at Belzec; 200,000 at Sobibor and 150-200,000 at Chelmno. Those were the estimates based on expert German witnesses and accepted in the German criminal prosecutions in the 1960s.

One prominent Holocaust historian, Gerald Reitlinger, estimated that perhaps 700,000 Jews perished at Auschwitz. French Holocaust historian Jean-Claude Pressac estimated in 1993 that the number of those who perished there was about 800,000 - of whom 630,000 were Jewish. Fritjof Meyer, a respected foreign policy analyst estimated that altogether 500,000 or 510,000 persons, Jews and non-Jews, perished in Auschwitz.

Comment: Please provide a reference to support your claim #1: including that there were orders and blue prints.

Comment: This might be a good start: http://www.yadvashem.org/yv/en/exhibitions/auschwitz_architecture/overview.asp

Comment: points 3 and 5 seem to support only that the people were killed, not how they were killed. As I understand the question it is mainly about the how though.

Comment: While your answer is a step in the right direction, it needs to avoid citing weak sources (personal cites blogs, wikipedia, etc), particularly on such an important subject. Instead of Wikipedia and personal blogs consider citing government agencies, academic research, published historians, and museum curators (as you do on occasion).

Comment: @example it could provide indirect support though, given that it would be difficult to kill that amount of people with alternative methods. I recall reading that this is actually the reason gas chambers were used - since other methods of killing (such as shooting) were too expensive and not efficient enough to kill large quantities.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that concentration camps weren't the only mechanism of mass killings the Nazis used... as they pushed into the Soviet Union and occupied large swaths of it, [they took to simply rounding up and shooting the "untermensch" in the occupied territories](http://www.ushmm.org/outreach/en/article.php?ModuleId=10007710).

Comment: @Oddthinking-References added for claim #1.

Comment: @Denten-All wikipedia references removed, only one personal blog source retained since it is a well sourced research which covers about 440 authentic references to SS guard Pery Broad!

Comment: @Example-Quoting Nizkor, "The exact method depended on the camp. Different means of killing -- sometimes only slightly different -- were used in different camps, and even in different places in the same camp. At Auschwitz, specifically at Krema I through III, the Zyklon-B was dropped through holes in the ceiling. The holes are visible in aerial photographs that happened to be taken by Allied reconnaissance planes."

Comment: Item 14 contains a typo or other mistake. The amounts add up to 12,000 kg.

Comment: @o.m.-The source had the same value of 1200 kg, thanks for the find and have added new source for the 12,000 kg value.

Comment: 12,000 is not a 160% *increase* from 7500, it is 160% *of* 7500, or a 60% *increase*.

Comment: I feel like all but the last quoted speech for #1 are irrelevant.  The question isn't about whether the Nazis wanted to kill Jews, but rather the method, and most of the quotes don't address the method.

Comment: @Bobson-The speeches were regarding the plans for extermination, not the actual methods!

Comment: How many did they fit in the gas chambers per cubic [meter?](http://holocaust.skeptik.net/documents/provan_gerstein.html)

Comment: @Mustang how is that relevant at all? None of the evidence posted here depends on how many people fit in the gas chamber. Furthermore there was more than one gas chamber at different locations, so your question doesn't even make sense.

Comment: So I should start a separate question?

Comment: @Mustang yes, if you are skeptical about the claim given in the statement you posted in your answer, then posting a new question about it would be the way to go.