# Are there only two remaining Holocaust gas chambers?

Tags: holocaust

Holocaust-denial site [Holohoax101](http://www.holohoax101.org) claims:

> According to the USHMM website - "Between 1941 and 1944, Nazi German authorities deported millions of Jews from Germany, from occupied territories, and from the countries of many of its Axis allies to ghettos and to killing centers, often called extermination camps, where they were murdered in specially developed gassing facilities."
>
> There are now only six alleged 'death camps', four were razed before the end of the war, and **two, Auschwitz and Majdanek, are still standing**.
>
> [...]
>
> The hoax gas chambers at Auschwitz and Majdanek are the only 'gas chambers' in existence.

Ignoring the claims of the chambers being hoaxes, are there only two remaining gas chambers from the Holocaust era?

Comment: I know this doesn't count as proof as it's personal experience, but I have personally seen the one in Dachau.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A well-traveled revisionist has contradicted this claim herself: [How many of the Nazi gas chambers are still in existence?](https://furtherglory.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/how-many-of-the-nazi-gas-chambers-are-still-in-existence/) She provides photographs of each.

As your source claims, of the extermination camps only Auschwitz and Majdanek have surviving gas chambers, and the one at Auschwitz is a reconstruction. But according to this blog as well as the more reliable source [*The Holocaust Sites of Europe: An Historical Guide*](http://www.ibtauris.com/Books/Humanities/History/History%20earliest%20times%20to%20present%20day/20th%20century%20history%20c%201900%20%20to%20c%202000/The%20Holocaust%20Sites%20of%20Europe%20An%20Historical%20Guide.aspx), there are also original gas chambers that survive in Mauthausen, Dachau and Stutthof. The claim as stated is not correct.

According to the US Holocaust Museum, the gas chamber at Dachau was [never used](https://www.ushmm.org/wlc/mobile/en/article.php?ModuleId=10005214).

See also: [Did the Nazis kill Jews using gas chambers?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/30469/22367)

Comment: Please keep comments constructive and on-topic.

Comment: The gas chamber in Hadamar also still exists (at least there is an image on Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%B6tungsanstalt_Hadamar#/media/File:Hadamar_012.JPG). This was used to kill handicapped or mentally ill people, though, so it might not be included in the number of "Holocaust Gas chambers".